# "Deep return" all the way back to first function call

Tags: python, function, return

Suppose I have two (or more) functions. One is higher level, processing stuff by calling different other functions. If one of these functions fails (e.g. Math error), I want to "abort" not only that function, but also the ones that called it. In my case I need this to escape an error and avoid having the rest of all calculations done, without quitting the whole process (which would also terminate my GUI). Instead, I want the script to continue running, but back on the upmost level.

This is an abstraction of my original problem:

```
def levelA(x):
    xx = levelB(x=x)
    xx *= 2
    return xx

def levelB(x):
    if x==0: return
    y = 10 / x
    return y

x = 0
print (levelA(x=x))
```

Initializing `x` with the value 0 would cause a crash in `levelB` when 10 is divided by `x`. So I first make sure that `x` is different from 0. If it's not, the function is aborted by calling return. Now `levelA` wants to continue with the doubling of the result of `levelB` which, in the case `x=0`, is "None" and there we go with another crash.

Of course, what I can do is inserting the line

```
if xx is None: return
```

before doing `xx *= 2`. But in my real case, there is not just one extra level, but 2 or even 3 and there are many different functions that are called. I want to avoid checking each and every output of the function for errors.

So my question is: Can I somehow go all the way back to the first function call and skip the ones that were in between? Something like a "deep return"?

Comment: `try` and `except` instead of using `if` and `else`. That's called [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). :)

Comment: Throw a custom exception and catch it in the first function?

Comment: `if x == 0: return` this returns `None` and renders your first function invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions were invented to handle the situation you describe. So, for example:

```
In [72]: def f1(x):
    ...:     return f2(x)
    ...:

In [73]: def f2(x):
    ...:     return f3(x)
    ...:

In [74]: def f3(x):
    ...:     if x > 0:
    ...:         return x
    ...:     else:
    ...:         raise ValueError("f3 called with negative argument")
    ...:

In [75]: try:
    ...:     print(f1(-2))
    ...: except ValueError as e:
    ...:     print(e)
    ...:
f3 called with negative argument
```

Comment: The important hint in your post is that I can raise a `ValueError` together with a string - that's the puzzle piece I was missing. It means I can basically catch everything and give it my own error message which is handled by my main routine!

Comment: Indeed. You can even define your own exceptions if you want.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you that I implemented ValueErrors all over my GUI constructor and now I capture all errors without having to exit the application of forcing it to crash. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

how about try/catch?

```
def levelA(x):
    xx = levelB(x=x)
    xx *= 2
    return xx

def levelB(x):
    if x==0: raise ZeroDivisionError
    y = 10 / x
    return y

try:
    x = 0
    print (levelA(x=x))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    // error handling or other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

> Initializing x with the value 0 would cause a crash in levelB when 10 is divided by x. So I first make sure that x is different from 0. If it's not, the function is aborted by calling return.

That's a good summary but you reached the wrong conclusion. You shouldn't `return`, you should raise an `Exception`. Then you can use a `try`, `except` clause wherever you want to handle that:

```
def levelA(x):
    xx = levelB(x=x)
    xx *= 2
    return xx

def levelB(x):
    if x==0: raise ValueError
    y = 10 / x
    return y

x = 0
try:
    print(levelA(x=x))
except ValueError:
    print('x was invalid! Wanna try again?')
```

Even better would be to just do the division and catch the Exception raised there:

```
def levelA(x):
    xx = levelB(x=x)
    xx *= 2
    return xx

def levelB(x):
    y = 10 / x
    return y

x = 0
try:
    print(levelA(x=x))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('x was invalid! Wanna try again?')
```

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of try and except, especially for the ZeroDivisionError. The problem is that my highest level handles all the exceptions together (and not the low-level). It's the class for my GUI that also contains functions to pop up message boxes. In the lowest level function I do not have those possibilities. So what I desire is a fast forward back to my highest level function that creates a MessageBox with the error that was thrown. Is that possible, too?

Comment: @offeltoffel Where you catch the exception and what you do in the except clause is up to you. You could put the `try` and `except` in the GUI code that forwards to the function and pop the messagebox in the except clause.